# Scout Eclipse key detect on row select

Tags: select, keypress, eclipse-scout

I want to know it is possible to detect which key is pressed when row in Table view is selected.

I need to have two different logic on row selected method if "shift" key is pressed or not.

```
@Override
public void rowsSelected(List<? extends ITableRow> rows) throws ProcessingException {
   if ("shift" is press) {
     do something....
   } else {
     do something else...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think that you have access to this information in the scout model in the `execRowsSelected` method.